# Convert Date-Time Stamp

Tags: java, date, time

I have an XML document that returns the following value for a date-time stamp:

`Wed, 18 Feb 2015 22:38:00 +0000`

How can I change this (using Java), so I can get this:

`Wednesday, February 18, 2015`

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

Have you this date as a string in java?

Try this:

```
String stringdate = "Wed, 18 Feb 2015 22:38:00 +0000";
    //Convert from string to date
    DateFormat stringformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = stringformat.parse(stringdate);

    //Convert from date to string
    DateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(newformat.format(date));
```

With timestamp:

```
Timestamp d = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Convert from date to string
    DateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(newformat.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, using SimpleDateFormat, the following should convert the date in the way required by your example.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args) throws ParseException {
        String input = "Wed, 18 Feb 2015 22:38:00 +0000";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        Date date = sdf.parse(input);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
        String dateString = format.format(date);
        System.out.println(dateString);
     }
}
```